# Alarm SET OFF AND ON in Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am creating a clock application that has alarm feature too. The time is showing up properly and I am also setting multiple alarm properly.

I am creating multiple alarm using different id and also saving the same into Database so that I can view the list of alarms in a listview. Now I am trying to set ON and OFF functionality for my alarm. I have a problem there.

On itemclick if alarm is ON it switches OFF with the help of:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this,TaskRecieverForAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main.this,  Integer.parseInt(cont[0]), intent, 0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.cancel(pi);
```

The above code cancels the alarms perfectly fine.

To switch ON the alarm I am using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, TaskRecieverForAlarm.class);
intent.putExtra("AlarmDate", cont[1]);
intent.putExtra("key", Integer.parseInt(cont[0]));
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main.this, Integer.parseInt(cont[0]) , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("daily"))
{
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1440*60000 ,sender);
 }
 else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("weekly"))
{ 
  am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);                 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 7*1440*60000 ,sender);
 }
```

Now as soon as I click the OFF to ON, alarm triggers and calls the TASKReceiverFORAlarm (broadcast receiver) even though the alarm time is 4 or 5 hours from the current time.  I am not sure where I am going wrong?

Can somebody help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that you need to use `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`, instead of `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, but that's just a guess. Please try it out and get back here wit hthe results.

Comment: Changed it but still the same. 

PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main.this, Integer.parseInt(cont[0]) , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

TO 
 
 PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main.this, Integer.parseInt(cont[0]) , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Comment: Ok, this doesn't work, try the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29):

```
public void setRepeating (int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation)

Added in API level 1
Schedule a repeating alarm. Note: for timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler. If there is already an alarm scheduled for the same IntentSender, it will first be canceled.

Like set(int, long, PendingIntent), except you can also supply a rate at which the alarm will repeat. This alarm continues repeating until explicitly removed with cancel(PendingIntent). If the time occurs in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately, with an alarm count depending on how far in the past the trigger time is relative to the repeat interval.

If an alarm is delayed (by system sleep, for example, for non _WAKEUP alarm types), a skipped repeat will be delivered as soon as possible. After that, future alarms will be delivered according to the original schedule; they do not drift over time. For example, if you have set a recurring alarm for the top of every hour but the phone was asleep from 7:45 until 8:45, an alarm will be sent as soon as the phone awakens, then the next alarm will be sent at 9:00.

If your application wants to allow the delivery times to drift in order to guarantee that at least a certain time interval always elapses between alarms, then the approach to take is to use one-time alarms, scheduling the next one yourself when handling each alarm delivery.

Parameters
type    One of ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP}, RTC or RTC_WAKEUP.
triggerAtMillis time in milliseconds that the alarm should first go off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the alarm type).
intervalMillis  interval in milliseconds between subsequent repeats of the alarm.
operation   Action to perform when the alarm goes off; typically comes from IntentSender.getBroadcast().
```

The way you use that function is:

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1440*60000 ,sender);
```

Try this one:

```
//The only variable here is the desired hour of the alarm, which
// has to be obtained in milliseconds
long alarmSetAt = // The hour of the Alarm for the current date in milliseconds
long time = cal.getTimeInMillis() - alarmSetAt;

if(time > 0){

  time = -time + cal.getTimeInMillis();
}
else{
  time = time + cal.getTimeInMillis() + 1440*60000;
}

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1440*60000 ,sender);
```